# Outlook email viewer visual studio .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I am relatively new to programming and I think I already know the answer to this but worth a shot anyway.

Is there anyway to view emails from outlook in a windows form within visual studio? If so is it also possible to open attachments from this email?

Thanks for help in advance.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can automate Outlook from your Windows Form application and get any information. For example, take a look at the [How to automate Outlook and Word by using Visual C# .NET to create a pre-populated e-mail message that can be edited](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819398) article which exaplins the basics.

Also you may find the [C# app automates Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) sample project.

Comment: Thanks for this Eugene but I am wanting the information to go from outlook into my windows form not windows form into outlook, I can do most of the things that it is saying on that webpage but can't find anything that pulls through the other way

Comment: I understood your post correctly. You can get all the required data to show on your windows form from Outlook by automating it (see the sample code).